# How to get the zonos store Id and API key for magento2?

Tags: magento2

I registered in zonos app account and i got the custom hello script via email.I copied that script in head tag of my website and setup the zonos app extension in local also.Now In admin configuration of zonos it showing storeId and ApI key fields are needed.please anyone help me how to get the zonos storeId and API key ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the store number and API key in the Zonos app account. Go to the "plugins" section and click on Magento as your plugin platform.

If you are using Zonos' new Dashboard, it can be found under "Integrate" and you can scroll down to the "App credentials" section.